# Compiling two executables into one C++

Tags: c++, makefile, clang++, huffman-code

Technically, this might not be an error within the makefile itself, but I wanted to double check if it was there or elsewhere.

I'm trying to make the executable with

```
CXX = clang++

CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -o

OBJECTSENC = huffmandec.o huffmanNode.o tree.o heap.o

OBJECTSDEC = huffmandec.o huffmanNode.o

.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp

all: encoder decoder

encoder: $(OBJECTSENC)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) encoder $(OBJECTSENC)

decoder: $(OBJECTSDEC)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) decoder $(OBJECTSDEC)

huffmanNode.o: huffmanNode.cpp huffmanNode.h
huffmandec.o: huffmandec.cpp huffmanNode.h
huffmanenc.o: huffmanenc.cpp huffmanNode.h tree.h heap.h
tree.o: tree.cpp tree.h
heap.o: heap.cpp heap.h

clean:
    /bin/rm -f *.o *~
```

but when I run it, I receive an error stating that I have an undefined reference to huffmanNode(int, char) in huffmandec.cpp. Normally, this would probably have a fairly straightforward solution, but when I compile the two separately (when only trying to make one executable), it runs just fine. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
the command line and error are

```
clang++ -Wall -g -o   -c -o huffmandec.o huffmandec.cpp
/tmp/huffmandec-21d583.o: In function `huffmanTree(huffmanNode*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char)':
/autograder/submission/huffmandec.cpp:18: undefined reference to `huffmanNode::huffmanNode(int, char)'
/autograder/submission/huffmandec.cpp:23: undefined reference to `huffmanNode::huffmanNode(int, char)'
/tmp/huffmandec-21d583.o: In function `main':
/autograder/submission/huffmandec.cpp:71: undefined reference to `huffmanNode::huffmanNode(int, char)'
/autograder/submission/huffmandec.cpp:103: undefined reference to `huffmanNode::getChar()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<builtin>: recipe for target 'huffmandec.o' failed
make: *** [huffmandec.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Is it the compilation or the link that fails? Can you also add the command line and the error message?

Comment: Please show exactly what you're running and what the output is. I assume the missing symbol is supposed to come from huffmanNode.o?

Comment: If you are using `g++` compiler , it's syntax will be like `g++ -o file1 file1.cpp file2.cpp file1.hpp` .

Answer (score 1):

You added the `-o` flag to `CXXFLAGS`. Don't do that, as `CXXFLAGS` is used by the built-in rules to compile .cpp files to .o. In this case, it has eaten the `-c` flag that stops the compiler from linking your object file into a library or program.